# How to download public AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I had https://pee2pee.s3.amazonaws.com/ which presented a XML file which started off like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"><Name>pee2pee</Name>
```

How would someone be able to download the entire contents of the bucket? When I try the following, I get a `Unable to load credentials error`

```
aws s3 cp s3://pee2pee.s3.amazonaws.com/ . --recursive
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--no-sign-request` option described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/)

```
aws s3 cp s3://pee2pee . --recursive --no-sign-request
```

Comment: Simply `s3://pee2pee` rather than `s3://pee2pee.s3.amazonaws.com/`

Comment: Oops, copied directly from the question without validating. Thanks :)